# Magento patches: unrecognized option --dry-run

Tags: magento-1.7, patches

I'm following the instructions at http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/apply-revert-magento-patches?icid=BLOG_php54_knowledgebase but not getting the listed results.  I have 3 sh patches downloaded into my magento root, but when I run them (sh patchname.sh) I immediately get a command prompt again. I'm not getting success or failure.  Just a bounce right back to the command prompt.  I'm running FreeBSD and the first patch I'm looking at specifies /bin/sh, which does in fact exist.  What am I missing here?

*edit*

I was downloading with IE.  On a whim I decided to try Chrome.  Appears the line ending handling is different.  The Chrome download version gives me:

> PATCH_SUPEE-2677_EE_1.13.0.2_v2.sh: 127: not found
>   PATCH_SUPEE-2677_EE_1.13.0.2_v2.sh: 127: not found
>   PATCH_SUPEE-2677_EE_1.13.0.2_v2.sh: 0: not found
>   Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
>   patch: unrecognized option `--dry-run'
>   Usage: /usr/bin/patch [options] [origfile [patchfile]] [+[options] [origfile]]...
>   Options:
>          [-cCeEflnNRsStuv] [-b backup-ext] [-B backup-prefix] [-d directory]
>          [-D symbol] [-F max-fuzz] [-i patchfile] [-o out-file] [-p[strip-count]]
>          [-r rej-name] [-V {numbered,existing,simple}] [--check] [--context]
>          [--prefix=backup-prefix] [--suffix=backup-ext] [--ifdef=symbol]
>          [--directory=directory] [--ed] [--fuzz=max-fuzz] [--force] [--batch]
>          [--ignore-whitespace] [--forward] [--reverse] [--output=out-file]
>          [--strip[=strip-count]] [--normal] [--reject-file=rej-name] [--skip]
>          [--remove-empty-files] [--quiet] [--silent] [--unified] [--version]
>          [--version-control={numbered,existing,simple}] [--index-first]
>   **ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.**

Not terribly informative as to why it won't install, but at least it's something more to work with.

Comment: If I recall correctly I just chmod +x them and ./patchname.sh

Comment: No go, that just bounces back immediately too.

Comment: Try removing the shebang line and passing it to sh

Comment: Same results. Very odd, I'd expect to get an error is a required tool was missing.  Why I don't get anything at all is baffling.  :-/

Comment: Question edited to add data collected.

Comment: What version are you running? Where did you get these patches? If you got them from Magento Support then you are better off dealing with them directly. This is the first I've ever heard of a patch other than the official releases that are just a drop in and re-apply the permissions.

Comment: @sr_magento - 1.7CE, so there's no support.  Patch is one of several on http://www.magentocommerce.com/download (at the bottom) that are drop in and run supposedly (per the instructions at http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/apply-revert-magento-patches?icid=BLOG_php54_knowledgebase).  Looks incredibly straightforward, should not require any permissions changes.  I've read the script and it all looks reasonable (just finds the tools and applies diffs).  Just doesn't seem to work.  Anybody manage to get the CE patches to work?

Comment: Digging into the "patch" command documentation I find that it's supposed to support the "--dry-run" option (which Magento depends on).  However, the patch command on my server does NOT support doing a dry run.  It's not an option...  Might just be as simple as compiling a new patch command.

Comment: Updated ports and built the latest version of patch.  No "dry-run" support in it.  Is it something that has been removed from "patch" recently and I could try an older version instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to modify the provided patch script.  In the _apply_revert_patch() function I had to replace `DRY_RUN_FLAG=" --dry-run"` with `DRY_RUN_FLAG=" --check"`.  After doing so the patch applied normally.