# Magento SUPEE-1533 5344 127: not found when patching

Tags: security

I'm having the following issue with the recent patches.

Magento CE Version 1.9.0.1

```
usr/home/******/public_html/****** > sh PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh

127: not found 127: not found 0: not found

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...

/usr/home/******/public_html/****** > sh PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh

127: not found 127: not found 0: not found

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...

patch: unrecognized option `--dry-run' Usage: /usr/bin/patch [options] [origfile [patchfile]] [+ [options] [origfile]]...

Options:
   [-cCeEflnNRsStuv] [-b backup-ext] [-B backup-prefix] [-d directory]
   [-D symbol] [-F max-fuzz] [-i patchfile] [-o out-file] [-p[strip-count]]
   [-r rej-name] [-V {numbered,existing,simple}] [--check] [--context]
   [--prefix=backup-prefix] [--suffix=backup-ext] [--ifdef=symbol]
   [--directory=directory] [--ed] [--fuzz=max-fuzz] [--force] [--batch]
   [--ignore-whitespace] [--forward] [--reverse] [--output=out-file]
   [--strip[=strip-count]] [--normal] [--reject-file=rej-name] [--skip]
   [--remove-empty-files] [--quiet] [--silent] [--unified] [--version]
   [--version-control={numbered,existing,simple}] [--index-first]

ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
```

Hopefully I'm missing something obvious here. If not can someone link to an article on manually applying the patches if such an article exists. I did have to manually remove the cache to get back into the back-end after this so I'm not sure if the patch did something.

As always thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

See [Magento patches: unrecognized option --dry-run](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/how-should-i-apply-magento-patches) - sounds like you're running on an OS with a different version of the patch command.